# What kind of Latex is this?

Tags: compiling

I need to make use of some old Latex code that open for public to copy/reuse. However I am not sure if this is the same Latex I use today. My complier doesnt understand it. Below is a part of the first lecture:

```
==Definitions and Notation==

'''Definition''' <math>\qquad</math> A '''set''' is a collection of objects called elements, numbers or points. 

'''Notation''' <math>\qquad</math> <math>\omega</math>∈<math>A</math> means <math>\omega</math> is an element of the set <math>A</math>. <math>\omega</math>∉<math>A</math> means <math>\omega</math> is not in the set <math>A</math>.
```

Reference: https://www.projectrhea.org/rhea/index.php?title=ECE600%20F13%20set%20theory%20review%20mhossain&action=edit

Can someone please help. This will save 10s of hours!

Comment: @AndréC, I don't think it is related. The code showed it is very strange. I think the problem is not `\qquad`.

Comment: I agree with @marmot. From the link we can find `'''Definition''' <math>\qquad</math> A '''set''' is a collection of objects called elements, numbers or points.`. Looks like some Wiki code tags.

Comment: @marmot, I am almost sure that it is some Wiki markup language. I tried to open the link and the source code appears. For example, `<center>[[Image:fig5_set_theory.png|400px|thumb|left|Fig 5: <math>A-B</math> is shown in green]]</center>`

Comment: "Looks like some Wiki code tags" - Yup. https://www.projectrhea.org/learning/about_Rhea.php says it's a Wiki.

Comment: The document is the source code of the html page https://www.projectrhea.org/rhea/index.php/ECE600_F13_set_theory_review_mhossain that can be inspected from web browsers, we see that it is Mathjax https://www.mathjax.org/

Comment: voting to close as offtopic.

Answer (score 4):

The document is the source code of the html page: [Topic 1: Set Theory Review](https://www.projectrhea.org/rhea/index.php/ECE600_F13_set_theory_review_mhossain)
that can be inspected from web browsers we see that it is [Mathjax](https://www.mathjax.org/) and more specifically Mathjax for Tex and LaTeX: [MathJax TeX and LaTeX Support](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html).

That's why we find LaTeX code like `\qquad`, `\omega`, `\Rightarrow`, etc

**Edition of screenshots:**

I have circled in red the HTML element "notation" as well as the menu "inspect the element". The right side shows the inspection window where you can see that Mathjax is being used.

[image: inspection-notation]

[image: mathjax]